# Android: Tapping editable TextView doesn't give it focus

Tags: android, focus, xamarin, android-edittext

I have several EditViews in my activity's layout with editable enabled. When the activity's view is brought up, the first EditView gains focus: there is a blinking cursor and soft keyboard. However I can't get focus on any of the other EditViews in order to type into them. I have them enabled and editable. What other things could cause this?

If I simply load the layout in the activity without running any of my code, this problem does not occur, so it must be caused in the code at runtime--this is a ton of ported legacy code that is too much to share, but I wonder what types of properties or method side effects could cause enabled EditViews to not receive focus when tapped.

Comment: You're not using an [`EditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)?

Comment: Woops, I am using EditText, not TextView, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this is having a Touch listener that does not set the event's TouchEventArgs.Handled property to true (I'm using Xamarin/monodroid vernacular here).

This was my code's problem. You must be sure to set TouchEventArgs.Handled to false. It was defaulting to true, which caused Android's handler which sets focus to not be run in the chain of responsibility!

```
                _view.Touch += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    Click(sender, new EventArgs());
                    args.Handled = false;
                };
```